# stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error: error 260

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I've got a small utility application that parses a csv-file and uses the data to fill a Core Data store for use with another application. I open the csv-file using `-initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` and the method always returns nil with the error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 UserInfo=0x100106450 "The file “data.csv” couldn’t be 
opened because there is no such file." Underlying Error=(Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "The 
operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"), {
NSFilePath = "/Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CreateData-
bhkmspyczgcfcrgehcbaydwdbfoa/Build/Products/Debug/data.csv";
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be 
completed. No such file or directory\"";
}
```

Now, I'm looking at that exact file in that exact directory. Even more confusing is the fact that I have another version of essentially the same utility for another app that works -- the only difference is the makeup of the core data store and entities and the number of columns in the csv file, all of which are invoked after loading the csv file. Or failing to load, as it were ...

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *csvFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:csvFilePath(QUESTIONS_INPUT_FILENAME) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error]; // This fails

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Returned error:\n%@, %@", error, [error userInfo]); // Returns the above error message
        exit(1);
    }

// ...
}

NSString *csvFilePath(NSString *inputFileName) {
    NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    return [resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:inputFileName];
}

NSString *applicationDocumentsDirectory() {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It fails because you aren't passing in the actual location of the file, just the filename, so it is trying to look for it in the program's own folder - you're using the path of the bundle. unless that's where your csv file is, it won't find it.

Comment: `csvFilePath` is the method returning the entire path.

Comment: Which happens to be the application bundle. unless he has the csv file in his application bundle, it can't find it.

Comment: The “unless he has the csv file in his application bundle” part is an important one. @royen, make sure you have the CSV file added to your project and included in the target's Copy Bundle Resources build phase. If your target is a command-line tool, not an application in a bundle, use of NSBundle makes very little sense; instead, set up your Xcode schemes to pass the filename as an argument.

Comment: Okay, this is really embarrasing -- turns out the error was between the keyboard and the chair. Sorry for wasting your time ...

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply the file path you passed is incorrect thus can't be found or does not exist.